# run Cython python setup.py build_ext --inplace, cs231n

Tags: cython

I am follow the standard **cs231n**, in the assignment2, when I run 
 python `setup.py` `build_ext --inplace`, on my **Mac os x** capitan, it always gives me back '`running build_txt`', and I think this is based on **Cython**, but It seems that this command doesn't work, i checked out that Ive gcc, so do you guys have any idea about this? here is the 
[tutorial](http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2016/assignment2/).

It works for my Ubuntu, but doesn't work on my Mac, I am not familiar with C, and Cython neither.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: ImportError: dlopen(cs231n/im2col_cython.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 cs231n/im2col_cython.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00

Comment: This is the error, after I run my script. Anyone could help me???

Comment: A [mcve] could be useful, i.e. include the code and setup.py.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add an comment but my reputation is not enough. I met the same problem, so I will introduce how I solve my problem.

My os is ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I use anaconda as the cs231n course recommend.When I ran

```
setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

It returns

```
running build_ext
```

And when I worked on jupyter notebook, I got the error:

```
NameError: global name 'col2im_6d_cython' is not defined
```

Then in the cs231n directory I deleted the fie im2col_cython, and ran

```
setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

After that, I worked on jupyter notebook, everything worked well.